# How to plot points in polar coordinates with point-specific color?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a figure like this below:

[image]

I already have 3d polar coordinate where 3rd dimension is amplitude (Q in above figure)
ex) {{110,10,0.15},{30,170,0.02},...}

Can anyone help me to make such a figure please?
Thank you!

Comment: What are your other dimensions? Are you using radians or degrees? Can you, please, give an example dataset that can be used to potentially answer your question? What have you tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the color of the point in the `PlotStyle`:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {200, 3}];
ListPolarPlot[{#} & /@ data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], PolarAxes -> True, 
     PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
     PolarGridLines -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ data[[All, 3]], 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

[image: Polar plot with point-specific colors]

However, as you see, each point has to be provided as a separate list.

Comment: Thank you very much!